# Riemann integrable function; approximation by step functions

Tags: calculus, integration

From the definition of a Riemann integrable function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ it follows that there exist sequences of step functions $\varphi_k$ and $\varphi^k$ with $\varphi_k \leq f \leq \varphi^k$ such that $\int f dx = \lim_k \int \varphi_k dx = \lim_k \int \varphi^k dx$.

My question: Can $\varphi_k$ and $\varphi^k$ be choosen to converge pointwise to $f$?

Comment: Almost everywhere or in all the points?

Comment: In all the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: the characteristic function of the Cantor set. Think what happens at $x=0$, for example.

Comment: That one isn't Riemann integrable, is it?

Comment: @wspin, is continuous in all the open intervals of the complementary of Cantor set.

Comment: allright, i got it. thank you